# Program ends after if while using loop when it shouldn't end

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop

I am making a simple calculator. The idea is it could loop over itself to let the user end the program. I added an *if* loop at the end of the program, but the program closes after loop. Note that when I remove the last *if*, the program loops just fine.

import math

```
    while True:
        print("Calculadora version 1.0")
        print("""Operaciones disponibles:
        1-Suma
        2-Resta
        3-Division
        4-Multiplicacion
        5-Radicacion
        6-Potenciacion
        7-Exponenciacion
```

#the code for the calculator

```
        end_prg = str(input("""Desea termiar el programa?
        (si/no) """))
        if end_prg==si:
            quit()
        elif end_prg==no:
            print("""




            """)
```

Comment: Instead of `if end_prg==si:` try `if end_prg=='si':`. Same for `no`.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is solved. It was a stupid begginer mistake, I forgot to write the options with "".